# In Griffith's experiment, if both S and R strains are added, can the R strain be isolated from the blood of the mice?

Tags: dna-replication, experiment

In Griffith's experiment on transformation, when both the S strain and the R strain were injected into the blood of the mice, could the R strain be isolated from the blood of the dead mice?

I think it's not possible as R strains are deactivated by the immune system of the mouse, but Wikipedia says both R and S strains were isolated from the dead mice.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: whether live r strain can be isolated from blood of the dead mice in griffith's experiment when injected with both virulent s strain and non virulent r strain

Comment: It would be nice if you could start sentences with a capital letter, and also use capital letters for people’s surnames. Question marks are needed after questions. If you did this it would show that you had made an effort in constructing your question and encourage us to answer it.

Comment: I have a suggestion if possible read the Griffith's experiment from Benjamin Peirce..

Answer (score -1):

S starin have capsule and cause infection.
R starin have no capsule and not cause infection.
According to griffith experiment S strain was killed by heat but R starin remain active, because S strain provide genatic information R strain. Then R strain use information to complete own structrure and reproduce itself.